# Sharing URLs from mobile in a Facebook page

Tags: facebook, url, mobile, share

I can post on a page that I've created on FB from m.facebook.com/page-id. When I post simple text, it shows that this was posted by the page. However, if I post a URL, it shows that me (not the page) is the publisher. Is there anyway to avoid this second case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible yet. Facebook does not allow it.

Answer (score 0):

Once you post it, if you refresh, you should be fine.

Let me know If that works for you.

Comment: It doesn't!
Can you show me a post in which you did that?